# play for java: app compiles using play compile but not when pushing to heroku; unresolved mongodb lib

Tags: java, mongodb, heroku, playframework-2.0

I have a java play application that I am trying to deploy to heroku using

```
git push heroku master
```

the application has deployed in the past but now does not compile during the deployment process.  I get package com.mongodb does not exist.  It compiles just fine using...

play compile

I have read...

http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Library-Dependencies.html#managed-dependencies

and other similar posts and have made adjustments to my build.sbt file in the libraryDependencies section.  Below is the relevant section.

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  "org.mongodb" % "mongo-java-driver" % "2.12.0"
)
```

Any ideas why it works using play compile and not in the deployment process to heroku?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Thanks Neil, for the editing.

Comment: Shouldn't that be "com.mongodb" not "org.mongodb" in your dependencies?

Comment: It is supposed to be "org.mongodb" here is the [url](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/2.12.0/) to the jar.  Changing "org" to "com" in the url results in a 404.

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad, I forgot the driver had a different dependency path to package name.

Comment: I don't know SBT at all, but in other build tools just because it's on the compile path doesn't necessarily mean it's being deployed.  You'll need to check the mongodb-java-driver jar is being deployed to heroku as well.